# Generating PDF of more than 100 pages in kartik-v/yii2-mpdf

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, mpdf

I am generating PDF of more than 100 pages. But it is taking 3-5 minutes to generate PDF. I want to make it upto 1 minute.

```
    use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
    $header = getPDFHeader();
    $body =  getPDFBody();
    $pdf = new Pdf([
                // set to use core fonts only
                'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
                // A4 paper format
                'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
                // portrait orientation
                'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT, 
                // stream to browser inline
                'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD, 
                // your html content input
                'content' => $body,  
                // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
                // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting 
                'cssFile' => '../../frontend/web/css/pdf.css',
                // set mPDF properties on the fly
                'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],
                 // call mPDF methods on the fly
                'methods' => [ 
                    'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
                ]
                ]);
$pdf->render();
```

I am new in yii2. I just want to generate it in less than 1 minute. What kind of settings am I missing? It is taking upto 5 minutes.

Comment: I believe you can't do anything about it in your code. As your pdf document is large, your server takes that much time processing it. What you can do is that increase your server's processing power and memory etc. Or otherwise you can ask the developer of mpdf to optimise internal code of extension to generate pdf document more fast.

Answer (score 1):

I've had much better performance by using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) and [a php wrapper to](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf).